# Create one file on change in another in Puppet

Tags: puppet

I try to manage a user password files with bcrypt hashed passwords. The password hashes will be created via puppet on each run. 
So now i have the problem that the file content of the user file is changed on each run.

My first idea was to manage a check file which contains a md5sum of the complete user hash to monitor any change on it. And i try to change the user file only if the check file was changed. 
But this does not work. This is because puppet file resources doesn't react on refresh events i guess?

This was my last try with an exec as extra instance.

```
$md5sum = md5(String($input_users_hash))

file { "${filename}.serial" :
  ensure  => present,
  content => $md5sum,
  notify  => Exec['md5sum_check']
}

exec { 'md5sum_check':
  command => '/bin/true',
  unless  => "test `cat /opt/tomcat/shared/classes/users.properties.serial` == ${md5sum}",
  notify  => File[$filename],
}

file { $filename :
  content => template($users_properties_template),
  require => Exec['md5sum_check']
}
```

Any useful hints to solve this and to prevent a flapping resource?

Comment: Would it not also be a problem that you are changing the passwords during every catalog application? Solving that problem also fixes your other one.

Comment: The passwords are always the same but the created hashes are always different. This conceptual part of such hashing algorithm are required.

Comment: Have you considered encrypting the passwords using dedicated software and Puppet bindings for retrieval? I do not know if this is for personal use or for a company, but most companies have dedicated software for this (instead of a `md5` Puppet function) that you could utilize which would also fix this problem.

Comment: I found a way to solve the issue i guess.
First I remove the unless clause because it is always true. The content and md5sum are always the same because of the resource ordering.
Second I changed the command to `rm ${filename}`, so if notify from `File["${filename}.serial"` arrives the exec is fired.
Third I add `replace => no` to `File[$filename]` to prevent file overwriting.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, my recommendation is that you store the bcrypt hashes in a hiera yaml on puppet server, and they are generated by something other than puppet (i.e. during the point where you create the new users).

If that isn't possible, and your avoiding directory service account management, then you need to find a bcrypt implementation that lets you choose set the salt.  Then for each username, you can hash it, and use it to stablize the salt for a given user, which should stabilize the passwourd output.

Comment: This is not what we are looking for. Storing of hashes is not an option because we need the possibilty to look for the correct password.